# Lightning performance with over 300 Data categories in knowledge

Tags: lightning, knowledge, performance, lightning-knowledge

I was surprised to read from the [lightning knowledge guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/lightning_knowledge_guide.pdf) that for orgs with over 300 Data Categories, if switching to lightning knowledge :

> "you may experience slower performance."

I was under the impression that Lightning experience overall was to provide a better performance and user experience with a new modern look. We don't have an org with 300+ Data categories, but could anyone shed any light on this specific setback?

(Has anyone with 300+ DataCategories actually migrated to lightning knowledge and confirmed this?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not mentioned in the latest release. Here is the new list:

- You can have only one article type when enabling Lightning Knowledge. Currently, there
  are no migration tools to help with merging your article types. To enable Lightning
  Knowledge, migrate your articles to one article type and disable or delete your other article
  types, or wait until migration tools are available to enable Lightning Knowledge.
- Submit for Translation action is not available in Lightning Knowledge. (You can still do this
  in Classic when Lightning Knowledge is enabled.)
- Creating or managing translations is not available in Lightning Knowledge. (You can still
  do this in Classic when Lightning Knowledge is enabled.)
- For articles with more than 30 versions, the versions above 30 show in Salesforce Classic, but not in Lightning Experience.
- After you enable Lightning Knowledge, the 'ArticleType' field is no longer accessible via SOQL (or the API). This can impact
  custom code that queries for the 'ArticleType' field.
- If your org currently has a Visualforce tab named "Knowledge," you get an "Insufficient Privileges" error when trying to access
  the Knowledge tab in Lightning Knowledge. To avoid this error you can rename or delete your existing Visualforce tab, or rename
  your Knowledge Base from "Knowledge" to something else

**References**

- [Lightning Knowledge Guide: Salesforce, Winter '18](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/lightning_knowledge_guide.pdf)
- [Lightning Knowledge Guide (Beta): Salesforce, Summer '17](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/lightning_knowledge_guide.pdf)

Comment: indeed, this has changed inbetween when the question was asked and the past 2 releases